# How could I find the correct values for every array that would lead me to unique summation number for every unique chain?

Tags: matrix, combinatorics

I have 9 arrays, each array has 9 values, I need to get the proper values in every value's position for every array, and that would give my a completely unique summations for every value's chain from every array.

If we assumed that I have these arrays:

```
array1=(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
array2=(11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91)
array3=(12,22,32,42,52,62,72,82,92)
array4=(13,23,33,43,53,63,73,83,93)
array5=(14,24,34,44,54,64,74,84,94)
array6=(15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95)
array7=(16,26,36,46,56,66,76,86,96)
array8=(17,27,37,47,57,67,77,87,97)
array9=(18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88,98)
```

Then if we calculate the summation of:

array1[0]+array2[1]+array3[1]+array4[1]+array5[1]+array6[1]+array7[1]+array8[1]+array9[1]

**We will get 206 total.**

And again, if we calculate the summation of:

array1[8]+array2[0]+array3[0]+array4[0]+array5[0]+array6[0]+array7[0]+array8[0]+array9[0]

**We will get 206 total..!!**

How could I find the correct values for every array that would lead me to unique summation number for every chain?

**Sorry for the missed UPDATE:**

I will follow the combination of (9, 3) of zeros to get the summation for every unique chain.
(i. e. I'll tray to multiply every possible chain with 84 combinations of 0/1 values: 111111000, 111110001, 111100011, 111000111, ....., 111101010,...etc).

Comment: Hi there. Are you using Mathematica for this?

Comment: ...and based on the structure of your arrays, you might just want to make sure that the numbers in the square brackets of your sum total to the same number... (and you'll get 36+90+squarebracketnumber*10)

Comment: @cormullion: I'm not sure what do you mean by this question, but what I need is a simple values or method to generate such values those leading me to unique total of unique chains' summation.

Comment: @ Pinguin Dirk: Accept my apologize, I didn't understand that.. :(

Comment: I meant that if you were using Wolfram Mathematica software you would need to use different syntax from what you've shown.

Comment: @ cormullion: I see, but i'm using PHP language to proof something.

Comment: @m.rizeg, then this is not the place for PHP questions. I'll migrate this to a more suitable site.

Comment: @m.rizeg somehow missed your comment that you aren't using *Mathematica*.  In light of this, regarding our earlier discussion, I'll let the StackOverflow folks try answering this to your satisfaction (after all there are a lot more of them).  You're still welcome in the Mathematica.SE chat room of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems underspecified.  Are you seeking the smallest numbers that have this property, or merely *any* set that will produce unique sums?  If it is the latter you could simply make sure that every array is of a different magnitude so that the sums cannot be equal:

```
Array[#2*10^# &, {9, 9}, {0, 1}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: I'm seeking "any set that will produce unique sums" actually, but "the smallest numbers that have this property" is highly preferred, too. Moreover, I've already used the suggested arrays, but it didn't success! maybe because I missed to inform you with a piece of information that I pasted it in my updated question..

Comment: @m.rizeg Let me see if I understand; another way to phrase the question update is that every set (array) must, in addition to the nine values, contain zero.  Is that correct?

Comment: See, If we assumed that we have this chain: array1[8]+array2[0]+array3[0]+array4[0]+array5[0]+array6[0]+array7[0]+array8[0]+array9[0]  I need first to multiply every element with the first test aarray wich is (1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), the result for this example will be (9,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000), finally, the resultant multiplicated arrays would be (9,10,100,1000,10000,100000) and the sum will be:111119

Comment: @m.rizeg I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did mistakenly "Added Comment" using "Enter" button that will add the comment instead of going to new line in comments text box..!

Comment: @m.rizeg Please join me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica).

Comment: It's correct, I used to use incorrect test equation..! sorry for that and thank you.